# Può una coordinata essere una subordinata allo stesso tempo? (considerando la relazione ad altre frasi)

Tags: grammar, grammatical-analysis

Ho un *dubbio sostanziale* sull'analisi del periodo.

Considero **e andare con lui al parco** dell'esempio seguente una semplice *coordinata alla subordianta interrogativa indiretta* (lo è rispettivamente a "se volevo abbandonare per un giorno la scuola") oppure la considero a sua volta una *subordinata interrogativa indiretta*  (lo è se penso che potrei mettere un se nella frase e avrebbe esattamente lo stesso valore di "se volevo abbandonare per un giorno la scuola"). E se fosse una subordinata interrogativa a sua volta di che grado sarebbe? Primo?

*"Abbiamo parlato un po’ e ad un tratto il mio amico mi ha chiesto se volevo abbandonare per un giorno la scuola e andare con lui al parco"*

Abbiamo parlato un po’ =principale
e ad un tratto il mio amico mi ha chiesto=coordinata alla principale
se volevo abbandonare per un giorno la scuola=subordinata interrogativa indiretta
e andare con lui al parco=coordinata alla subordinata interrogativa / subordinata interrogativa

Comment: Anche in questo esempio: "Improvvisamente ho visto mio zio, che mi ha guardato con sorpresa, MA NON MI HA FERMATO."

"Ma non mi ha fermato" può essere una coordinata avversativa (visto il ma), ma anche una subordinata relativa 1st grado se immagino che sia stato tralasciato un che per non ripetersi "ma CHE non mi ha fermato".

Comment: Stessa questione per questa frase nell'analisi di "e di fermarsi". 

Martina decise, ignorando gli avvertimenti che la madre le aveva rivolto, di seguire i consigli dello sconosciuto e di fermarsi a comprare delle rose per la nonna.

Martina decise, =principale
ignorando gli avvertimenti =sub modale 1st grado
che la madre le aveva rivolto,=sub relativa 2nd grado
 di seguire i consigli dello sconosciuto =sub oggettiva 1st grado
e di fermarsi = coordinata alla sub oggettiva 1st grado e subordinata di 1st grado 
a comprare delle rose per la nonna.=subordinata finale 2nd grado

Comment: A proposito della frase sullo zio sorpreso con l'avversativa, avevi visto il mio commento alla tua domanda «La soggettività dell'analisi del periodo, seriamente?»?

Comment: Adesso sì. Tu dici "scelta l'interpretazione, ne deriva l'analisi", spero proprio che la mia prof la pensi allo stesso modo!

Comment: (Abbiamo parlato un po’) **e** (a un tratto il mio amico mi ha chiesto [**se** (volevo abbandonare per un giorno la scuola) **e** (andare con lui al parco)]). Esiste una metodologia accettata per inserire parentesi come sopra (parsing?) (non sono un linguista).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sì. La coordinazione e la subordinazione sono rapporti tra proposizioni, non sono attributi della proposizione a sé stante.

> (1) Abbiamo parlato un po’
>
> e
>
> (2) ad un tratto il mio amico mi ha chiesto
>
> se
>
> > (3) volevo abbandonare per un giorno la scuola
> >
> > e
> >
> > (4) [volevo] andare con lui al parco

Il rapporto tra (1) e (2) è di coordinazione. Il rapporto tra (2) e (3) è di subordinazione. Il rapporto tra (3) e (4) è di coordinazione. Il rapporto tra (2) e (4) è di subordinazione. Tra la (1) e la (3) o la (4) non c'è nessun rapporto.

La (4) è una subordinata della (2) e anche una coordinata della (3).